# Transferring control between two spring apps in distributed system, docker containers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-container, docker-network

I have two or more containers in a docker network, they are spring apps, these spring apps sometimes needs to transfer the control to each other, for example, some spring app is responsible to login users, and when they are logged in it will transfer the control to another processing spring app in another container, and if the user sends subsequent requests, it should be forwarded to the processing app, and i don't want the login app to be receiving the subsequent requests because that could create an overload for the login app, so how I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "transferring control"?  You could use something like an Nginx container as a reverse proxy to route inbound HTTP requests to one container or another, which sounds most like the flow you're describing.  But possibly you want to use a Spring `WebClient` to call the other service?  Or use Spring Cloud Stream in combination with RabbitMQ to start asynchronous work in the other container?

Comment: @DavidMaze 
I can use the RabbitMQ to send messages to the processing app, but then how I can automatically forward the subsequent requests to the processing app, there might be multiple processing apps, how I can forward it to the processing app specified by the login app, Nginx can be used here, but how it can notice what processing app it should forward to, I can use login app to automatically forward the logged in users, but this might overload it with many requests